# How to extract file contents and pass in as command line parameters in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

I need to run a command:

```
python test.py command --option 1 value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
```

(upto value100)

I have a text file with space separated values, like:

> value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 ..

How can I pipe this into the command without copying and pasting the entire file content into the terminal?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Bash command substitution feature:

```
python test.py command --option 1 $(<file.txt)
```

From [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

```
Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace
the command name. There are two forms:

$(command)

or

`command`

Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing
the command substitution with the standard output of the command,
with any trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not
deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting. The
command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the
equivalent but faster $(< file).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
python test.py command --option 1 `cat file.txt`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
xargs -a file.txt python test.py command --option 1
```